# Can't make sense of (UTM?) boundaries coordinates from Statistics Canada

Tags: utm, boundaries, canada

I downloaded a GML file of cities boundaries from Statistics Canada, but I can't make sense of them. For example, when looking at the boundaries for a city north of Toronto (Markham), the first coordinate pair in the list (gml:posList tag) is 7232029.8171445 964392.282857482.

It looks like the coordinates are in UTM format, but when I plug the numbers into a [converter](http://rcn.montana.edu/resources/Converter.aspx) online to see them in long/lat using NAD83 and zone 17, it points to somewhere in the middle of the Atlantic Ocean.

The coordinates are accompanied by a PDF file that specifies the following geographic representation, but it still doesn't seem to help. I tried subtracting the false easting and northing values, but that doesn't result in proper coordinates.

- Projection: Lambert conformal conic
- False easting: 6200000.000000
- False northing: 3000000.000000
- Central meridian: -91.866667
- Standard parallel 1: 49.000000
- Standard parallel 2: 77.000000
- Latitude of origin: 63.390675
- Linear unit: metre (1.000000)
- Datum: North American 1983 (NAD83)
- Prime meridian: Greenwich
- Angular unit: degree
- Spheroid: GRS 1980

If anyone can provide some help on how to properly convert these numbers to long/lat it would be very helpful. I want to overlay them on a map in a custom application, so I can't just get the data in another format that's compatible with specific GIS apps.

Comment: Projection is EPSG:3347 (NAD83 / Statistics Canada Lambert).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numeric values you are seeing are map coordinates but not UTM. The information you shared identifies the projection as Lambert conformal conic. This is EPSG:3347, known in QGIS as NAD83 / Statistics Canada Lambert.

Also documented on [spatialreference.org](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3347/)